# Bar Chart dynamic entries work only when reverted (ascending)

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart

I use charts from https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts

Third-party API generates JSON data (year : count) for chart in descending order, from the new to old ones.

When I try to fulfill BarChartDataEntries in descending order (as I get from API), there are still X Axis labels in ascending order and strange empty columns as on video below.
[image]

But as soon as I change to reverted, everything looks good.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        statisticServices.getStatistics() { _ in
            self.setBarChart(statistics)
        }
    }
    
    private func setBarChart(_ statistics: [Statistics]){
        var ordinEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
        
        for i in 0..<statistics.count { //(0..<statistics.count).reversed()
                        
            guard let dosarYear = Double(statistics[i].dosarYear),
                  let totalCount = Double(statistics[i].successCount) else {
                print("No statistic data for the chart")
                return
            }
                        
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(
                x: dosarYear,
                y: totalCount,
                data: statistics[i]
            )
            ordinEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        
        let chartData = BarChartData()
        let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: ordinEntries)
        dataSet.highlightColor = NSUIColor(cgColor: redColor.cgColor)
        dataSet.highlightAlpha = 1.0
        dataSet.barBorderWidth = 0
        dataSet.valueFont = UIFont(name: "Rockwell", size: 9)!
        dataSet.colors = [NSUIColor(cgColor: blueColor.cgColor)]
        
        chartData.addDataSet(dataSet)
        
        barChartView.data = chartData
        barChartView.delegate = self
        
        barChartView.legend.enabled = false
        barChartView.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white
        barChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false

        barChartView.leftAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [4,4]
        barChartView.leftAxis.gridColor = UIColor.rgb(0xc6c6c6)
        barChartView.leftAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "Rockwell", size: 9)!
        barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
        barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
        barChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
        //barChartView.setVisibleXRange(minXRange: 3.0, maxXRange: 3.0)
        barChartView.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(6.0)
        
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0)
    }
```

Comment: Please, post some code...it's impossible for someone to help you without code...

Comment: @AntonioWar Thanks for noting, I was so caught up in the screenshots that I forgot to add the code...